# How to avoid nested loop in a real Javascript coding test

Tags: javascript, loops, nested

Between two input arrays, find the same array or arrays and return them.

I just could come up with nested loop solution.

```
const compareArrs = (arr1, arr2) => {
  const rtnArr = []
  for (let ar1 of arr1){
    for (let ar2 of arr2){
      if (JSON.stringify(ar1) === JSON.stringify(ar2)){
        rtnArr.push(ar1)
      }
    }
  }
  return rtnArr
}

// compare [1, 2] [3, 4] with [1, 2]
console.log(compareArrs([[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[1, 2]]))
```

[[1, 2]] should be returned.

Comment: I don't think this question should be voted down as he is asking a question about how to do the above in a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map each subarray of one argument and put it into a Set. With the other argument, iterate through it, stringifying as you go, and find the element for which the stringified array is already in the Set, for an overall complexity of `O(N)`:

```js
const compareArrs = (arr1, arr2) => {
  const arr1StringifiedSet = new Set(arr1.map(JSON.stringify));
  return arr2.find(
    subarr2 => arr1StringifiedSet.has(JSON.stringify(subarr2))
  );
};

console.log(compareArrs([[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[1, 2]]));
```

(In comparison, a nested loop has a complexity of `O(N^2)`)

As comment notes, if you actually need *all* matching arrays, not just the first, then use `.filter` instead of `.find`:

```js
const compareArrs = (arr1, arr2) => {
  const arr1StringifiedSet = new Set(arr1.map(JSON.stringify));
  return arr2.filter(
    subarr2 => arr1StringifiedSet.has(JSON.stringify(subarr2))
  );
};

console.log(compareArrs([[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[1, 2]]));
```

Comment: I believe the second argument can have more than one element, otherwise there is no sense for it to be an array. If this is the case, you can use `filter()` in replace of `find()`.

Comment: The question says `find the same array and return them.`, so I took that to mean that there'd be *one* matching element. Of course, if he wants to find *all* matching arrays, use `filter` instead

Comment: Yeah, could be, however as a non-native english speaker, and taking myself as an example of this, sometimes we don't write exactly what we need. Just saying :)

Comment: Sorry for making a confusion, Like Shidersz said, there could be multiple matching arrays. I just modified my question.

Comment: @JinYongKim It sounds like your expected output is actually `[[1, 2]]`, not `[1, 2]`, if you want the result to be an array of all matching arrays?

Comment: Yes, you're right, I edited my question again. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1):

You can mimic a set of arrays with nested maps, where [1, 2] becomes an entry in the root map where the key is 1 and the value is another map with a key 2, like this:

```
const present = Symbol('present');

class ArraySet {
    constructor() {
        this._root = new Map();
    }

    add(array) {
        let node = this._root;

        for (const item of array) {
            if (node.has(item)) {
                node = node.get(item);
            } else {
                node.set(item, node = new Map());
            }
        }

        node[present] = true;
    }

    has(array) {
        let node = this._root;

        for (const item of array) {
            node = node.get(item);

            if (node === undefined) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return !!node[present];
    }
}
```

then:

```
const compareArrs = (arr1, arr2) => {
    const set = new ArraySet();
    arr1.forEach(set.add, set);
    return arr2.filter(set.has, set);
};
```

```js
const present = Symbol('present');

class ArraySet {
    constructor() {
        this._root = new Map();
    }

    add(array) {
        let node = this._root;

        for (const item of array) {
            if (node.has(item)) {
                node = node.get(item);
            } else {
                node.set(item, node = new Map());
            }
        }

        node[present] = true;
    }

    has(array) {
        let node = this._root;

        for (const item of array) {
            node = node.get(item);

            if (node === undefined) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return !!node[present];
    }
}

const compareArrs = (arr1, arr2) => {
    const set = new ArraySet();
    arr1.forEach(set.add, set);
    return arr2.filter(set.has, set);
};

console.log(compareArrs([[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[1, 2]]));
```

That takes time proportional to `arr1.concat(arr2).flat().length`. Another approach that works as long as you can create an appropriate comparison function for the arrays, like this lexicographic one for when the usual JavaScript operators give a total ordering:

```
const lexCompare = (a, b) => {
    const len = Math.min(a.length, b.length);

    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (a[i] < b[i]) return -1;
        if (a[i] > b[i]) return 1;
    }

    return a.length - b.length;
};
```

**and the input arrays contain no duplicates** is to sort the combination of both arrays first:

```
const sorted = arr1.concat(arr2).sort(lexCompare);
```

then look for duplicates created by the merge right beside each other:

```
return sorted.filter((item, i) => {
    if (i === 0) return false;

    const prev = sorted[i - 1];
    return prev.length === item.length && prev.every((x, i) => x === item[i]);
});
```

in time O((|arr1| + |arr2|) log (|arr1| + |arr2|) l) where l is the maximum array length. You can reduce that (|arr1| + |arr2|) log (|arr1| + |arr2|) to |arr1| log |arr1| + |arr2| log |arr2| but it might end up being slower.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) combined with [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and [Array.prototype.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

```js
const compareArrs = (arr1, arr2) => arr1.reduce((a, c) => {
  const found = arr2.find(arr => JSON.stringify(arr) === JSON.stringify(c))
  if (found.length) a.push(found)
  return a
}, [])

// compare [1, 2] [3, 4] with [1, 2]
console.log(compareArrs([[1, 2]], [[1, 2], [3, 4]]))
```

Comment: This one actually has a slower worst case than the code in the question because of pushing with array spread.

Comment: @Ry- You right, I have improved my answer by using Array#concat().. Thanks for the comment

Comment: `[].concat` is the same thing, though. You’d need to use `push`.

Comment: @Ry- Updated answer, thank you so much for the comments